# Error: Cannot find control with path: "department -> departmentName"

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have a problem with "binding" my FromGroup from .ts file to my .html file. 
I have tried to study the other stackoverflow questions and possible answers, and tried them on my application, but I still get multiple errors.

As you guys can see I start off calling [formGroup] and set it to chartsForm.

I then tell Department "class" that it's into array group by using formArrayName following by formControlName to specify the control.

So, my problem is: How can HTML not find the controls? I have declared formArrayName to the department array and formControlName = departmentName, which you guys can see on .ts file. Where have I possible screwed up?

**chart.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="chartsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">


            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="hospital" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Hospital:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hospital" placeholder="Hospital name"
                        formControlName="hospitalName" required>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row" formArrayName="department">
                <label for="department" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Department:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="department" placeholder="Department"
                        formGroupName="departmentName">

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row" FormArrayName="ward">
                <label for="ward" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Ward:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10" formArrayName="ward">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ward" placeholder="Ward" formControlName="wardName">
                </div>
            </div>


            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!chartsForm.valid">Submit</button>



            <p>
                Form Status: {{ chartsForm.value | json }}
            </p>

            <p>
                Form Valid: {{ chartsForm.status }}
            </p>





        </form>
```

**chart.component.ts:**

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

    chartsForm: FormGroup

    constructor(private _chartService: ChartService, private fb: FormBuilder, private cookieService: CookieService) {}


    ngOnInit(): void {

    this.chartsForm = this.fb.group({
                hospitalName: ['', Validators.required],
                department: this.fb.array([this.korrektJsonOpsætning()]),
     })


        // console.log(JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get('test')));
    }

    korrektJsonOpsætning(): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
            departmentName: ['Intensiv afd.'],
            ward: this.fb.array([{
                wardName: ['ward1'],



           }])

        })
    }

    onSubmit() {

        console.log(this.chartsForm.value); 

        // this.cookieService.set('test', JSON.stringify(this.chartsForm.value));
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't use `formControlName` inside `formArray`. You have to use indices. https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: Fair point but what if I want to achieve something like this? How can this be achieved? Is it the same way? https://prnt.sc/mqs9u2